# How to reshape an array faster?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large array (`arr`) of size `22 X 225 X 225` and I want it to be reshaped to a size of `22 X 50625`. `ArrayReshape` can do it perfectly well. However, it is too slow.

Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: There is hardly any faster way than `ArrayReshape`. For the matrix `A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {22, 225, 225}];`, my machine runs `B = ArrayReshape[A, {22, 50625}]; // RepeatedTiming` in `0.00072` seconds. Try to use [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/38178).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I was thinking to flatten each of the `22` arrays of `225 X 225`.

Comment: That could be done with `Flatten[A, {{1}, {2, 3}}]` or `Flatten /@ A`, but is much slower, at least in the current version (11.3).

Comment: Almost the same for me in 11.1.
`ArrayReshape`: .0064, `Join@@@A`: .0064, `Flatten/@A`: .0048. Interestingly, ArrayReshape is the only one that does not unpack.

Comment: I get on order 0.01 sec for both `ArrayReshape` and `Flatten/@A` (`Flatten` marginally faster) with v11.1.1/linux. Something change w/ 11.3?  ( I doubt your hardware is 10x faster than mine.. )

Comment: .. (oops  I was using `AbsoluteTiming` . `RepeatedTiming` does give a much faster time here )

Comment: @george2079 Might be so. In version 11.0.1, the example above needs `0.00279`, hence four times longer. I also believe to recall that combinations of `Flatten` and `Partition` have been faster than `ArrayReshape` in earlier versions.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, somebody must have put some effort in optimizing `ArrayFlatten`. That's good to see!

Here a benchmark for different methods and array sizes:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
funs = <|
   "ArrayReshape[#,{...}]&" -> (ArrayReshape[#, {Dimensions[#][[1]], 
        Times @@ Dimensions[#][[2 ;; 3]]}] &),
   "Flatten[#,{{1},{2,3}}]&" -> (Flatten[#, {{1}, {2, 3}}] &),
   "Map[Flatten,#]&" -> (Map[Flatten, #] &),
   "Compile[...][#]&" -> (Compile[{{a, _Real, 2}},
        Flatten[a],
        RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
        Parallelization -> True,
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
        ][#] &),
   "Partition[Flatten[#],...]&" -> (Partition[Flatten[#], 
       Times @@ Dimensions[#][[2 ;; 3]]] &)
   |>;
nlist = 2^Range[2, 9];
benchmark = Benchmark[Values[funs], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {#, #, #}] &, 2^Range[2, 9]];

g = ListLogLogPlot[
  AssociationThread[
   Map[Style[#, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"] &, Keys[funs]],
   benchmark
   ],
  Joined -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Timings on Mathematica ", $Version}],
  ImageSize -> Large,
  AxesLabel -> {"n", "Time (s)"},
  Ticks -> {nlist, Automatic}
  ]
```

[image]

[image]

Both performed on Intel 4980 HQ @ 2,8 GHz, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3.

Answer (score 5):

This is a little too long for a comment. On my machine (MMA 11.2, Win7-64bit), there is a signifcant difference in performance between `ArrayReshape` and a direct `Flatten` application, with `ArrayReshape` being roughly 3x faster:

```
arr = RandomReal[1, {22, 225, 225}];

RepeatedTiming[ArrayReshape[arr, {22, 50625}];]    (* Out: {0.0065, Null} *)
RepeatedTiming[Flatten[arr, {{1}, {2, 3}}];]       (* Out: {0.019, Null}  *)

RepeatedTiming[Flatten /@ arr;]                    (* Out: {0.2, Null}    *)
```

Mapping `Flatten` is very slow in comparison.

The mapping method also unpacks the array:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ@arr                                   (* Out: True  *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ@ArrayReshape[arr, {22, 50625}]        (* Out: True  *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ@Flatten[arr, {{1}, {2, 3}}]           (* Out: True  *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ@(Flatten /@ arr)                      (* Out: False *)
```

Comment: Yepp, using `Map` should not be encouraged as much as several years before. When I _have_ to map over packed arrays, I try to do so with a `Listable` CompiledFunction`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher oh no, that's not what i want to hear! a lot of my code is strongly based around mapping; i guess i'll be on the lookout for alternate methods in the future.

Comment: @BenKalziqi Of course, you could do much worse than `Map`ping, e.g. with `For`. ;) Of course, you have to balance effort for prototyping, debugging, and maintaining vs. pure runtime. And `Map` is usually a good trade-off.